# printing from main page in pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qprinter

i write some code in pyqt5 that create a table in main main:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow): ...
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):...
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "print"))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.printer)
    def printer(self):...
```

and use this class by:

```
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

i wanna know how can i print from main page of my program?

Comment: Print what? Where? To the console?

Comment: @mFoxRU printing main page - to printer

Comment: So you want to print a "screenshot" of your window?

Comment: @mFoxRU yeah. an screenshot of main page of program...(not all of the window)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done rather easy using [QPrinter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprinter.html) class.

Below is well-commented example of how to do it.

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtPrintSupport


class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Create some widgets
        self.setGeometry(500, 500, 300, 300)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(
            'Print QTextEdit widget (the one below)', self)
        self.button.setGeometry(20, 20, 260, 30)
        self.editor = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(
            'Wow such text why not change me?', self)
        self.editor.setGeometry(20, 60, 260, 200)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.print_widget)

    def print_widget(self):
        # Create printer
        printer = QtPrintSupport.QPrinter()
        # Create painter
        painter = QtGui.QPainter()
        # Start painter
        painter.begin(printer)
        # Grab a widget you want to print
        screen = self.editor.grab()
        # Draw grabbed pixmap
        painter.drawPixmap(10, 10, screen)
        # End painting
        painter.end()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = App()
    gui.show()
    app.exec_()
```

To print whole window just replace `screen = self.editor.grab()` with `screen = self.grab()`

Comment: How to enable preview dialog before printing?